# I need countBy to include "zero" occurrences to keep the array length in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

I'm using the Laravel Eloquent's **countBy( $key_name )** method on this Collection:
(Values can only be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5).

```
$collection = [
    {
        "atencionMesero": "4",
        "rapidezServicio": "2",
        "calidadComida": "1",
        "experienciaGeneral": "5"
    },
    {
        "atencionMesero": "4",
        "rapidezServicio": "2",
        "calidadComida": "3",
        "experienciaGeneral": "5"
    },
    {
        "atencionMesero": "5",
        "rapidezServicio": "5",
        "calidadComida": "5",
        "experienciaGeneral": "5"
    },
]
```

So if I use $collection->countBy( 'rapidezServicio' ) I get this result:

```
{
    "2": 2,
    "5": 1,
}
```

But I need a function to include the "zero" occurrence, like so:

```
{
    "1": 0,
    "2": 2,
    "4": 0,
    "5": 1,
    "3": 0
}
```

The order doesn't matter, I can simply use ksort() on the final result, but I've been struggling for days to make it work like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result of `countBy` and add it with a default array. The result will be what you need.

```
$yourArray = ["2" => 2, "5" => 1];
$defaultArray = ["1" => 0, "2" => 0, "3" => 0, "4" => 0, "5" => 0];

$finalArray = $yourArray + $defaultArray;
```

$finalArray would be:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [5] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

and you can sort it